# How to use Up/Down arrows to navigate textboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have the following page:

```
          <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var current = "";


        function Tab(e) {
            var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
            var unicode = evtobj.charCode ? e.charCode : evtobj.keyCode;


            var targ;
            if (evtobj.target) targ = evtobj.target;
            else if (evtobj.srcElement) targ = evtobj.srcElement;


            if (unicode == 37) {
                var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    if (elements[i].tabIndex == targ.tabIndex - 1) {
                        elements[i].focus();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (unicode == 39) {
                var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    if (elements[i].tabIndex == targ.tabIndex + 1) {
                        elements[i].focus();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="return Tab(event);">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TabIndex="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TabIndex="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" TabIndex="3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" TabIndex="4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" TabIndex="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

        <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" TabIndex="6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" TabIndex="7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" TabIndex="8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" TabIndex="9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" TabIndex="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

It works fine with Right/Left arrows navigation depending on the tab index for each textbox, I need to do the same with the Up/Down arrows, to navigate up and down by setting focus on the textbox above or under the current text box, for example, if focus is on textbox 3 and I press down arrow the focus should move to textbox 8 as it's under it, and vis versa.

Comment: current code moves +1 or -1. have you tried +5 and -5?

Comment: Thanks it works, but I still need modification as in my real case I don't have the same number of textboxes in each row. So it's not always +/- 5

Comment: You can use `unicode == 37 || unicode == 38` & `unicode == 39 || unicode == 40` respectively. Here is JS keycodes for arrow keys: 37 = left, 38 = up, 39 = right, 40 = down.

Comment: any way you can make number of textboxes/row a requirement? or is there some way of figuring out how many will be in a row? you are using `getElementsByTagName` so you can already get a count of elements from that. then maybe you can figure out how many to move +/-.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto will using the up or down code actually move focus up or down one row? they're not really rows.

Comment: @wazz Let's say that textboxes 1,2,3 are in first row .. and text boxes 4,5 in the second row and the remaining textboxes are in third row. Can you write the code needed please?

Comment: i was hoping you'd have the same number of textboxes in each row. and, no.